# Index Maintenance Plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index-maintenance

At our organisation we are migrating to SQL Server from visual foxpro dbf and hence had no maintenance plans and have no DBA. We have gone through our backup plans and Index maintenance is only index rebuild as and when required.

I wanna propose a new plan for index maintenance but wanna be sure if am wrong about it.its like Daily Index reorganizing and index rebuild as and when required (weekly or as late as monthly).

As I understand reorganize can be done online and will reduce accumulation of fragments.

Does clustered index duplicate the table or it just reorganizes the table?

Also would like to know if there are any other aspects of sql server maintenance that i need to look-up.

Sorry for so many question, just curious about many things.

Comment: You can watch this 1 hour video by Paul Randal -- [Index Fragmentation: Internals, Analysis, and Solutions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3SXxclj_vg&list=UUCN1vyLawxrXAiTQoi3lNow)! There is no better explanation than this.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://ola.hallengren.com/

He has a great maintenanceplan which is free to use. I am using it for every project.